# Joining two tables in R provides wrong output

Tags: r, join, statistics, data-cleaning, panel-data

I am trying to create panel data set by joining Table 1 and Table 2

Table 1

[image: Table 1]

Table 2

[image: Table 2]

The output I would like to receive is that I will have 4 columns:

Powiat | Rok | Liczba bezrobotnych | Srednie wynagrodzenie

When I try to join these two tables with this line of code:

```
newtable <- left_join(bezrobotni, srednie, by = "Powiat",relationship = "many-to-many")
```

I receive such output:

[image: Wrong output]

I tried with different joins but the result is always this same. Do you know how to make it right?

Comment: try `by = c("Powiat", "Rok")`

Comment: @Julian has the right idea above.  I would just add that if you aren't familiar with table joins and are expecting to keep the full match set from both Table 1 and Table 2, you should use a `full_join()`.